# an issue with php pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to print last post from specific category
Could you please help me with the code?
I want to put on `$record` manual, for example: I put `"design"`, and just show the last post in *design category*.
And one thing: table `blog` it's separate from table `record`.

thanks

```
<?php $category = $record ['record']; { ?>
<?php foreach($db->query("select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc") as $row){ ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
        <div class="gallery-item"><img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"></div>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What is an issue getting now and what your expected output?

Comment: Try this query `select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: You have been asked what results you're getting now as opposed to the desired results. Can you interact with people in comments please? So that you can clarify your question. @Ebi Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent post, you could change your SQL to select it.
Try something like this:

```
select * from blog where category = '$category' order by {DATE_FIELD} desc limit 1
```

You need to exchange the string {DATE_FIELD} with the actual date field in your table. This select would return the most recent dataset and only that one.

EDIT: You can also sort by youre id if the date isn't changed or the changed date is stored in another field.

```
select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: could you please explain with an example

Comment: just load the return of your select in a variable like this: 
$postData = $db->query("select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc limit 1").
After that you can access all information with $postData['FIELDNAME']. For example $postData['image'] or $postData['title'] etc.

Comment: $postData['image'] or $postData['title'] will only work if this fields exists. I just assumed that because of the code you provided. If you want to know what properties are available do a var_dump <?php var_dump($postData) ?>

Comment: i have problem with this code
<?php $category = $record ['record']; { ?>
the one you said it's working, i have some record on the the different i want to get that record..
for example <?php $category = $record ['design']; { ?>
 $postData = $db->query("select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc limit 1")
but this code doesn't work..

Comment: in this line: "  <?php $category = $record ['design']; { ?> $postData = $db->query("select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc limit 1")  " youre closing the php right after "  $category = $record ['design']; { "  with the "?>" amd the is a wrong closing bracket. You need to remove the closing bracket and move the "?>" at the end of your php statement like this: <?php $category = $record ['design']; $postData = $db->query("select * from blog where category = '$category' order by id desc limit 1") ?>

Comment: And if this answers your question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: i want to said $category equally $record['record'];
how i can do that?
i tried $category = $record['record'];
but doesn't work

thanks

Comment: Please make sure that $record has a property called record. Try a var_dump on $record like this <?php var_dump($record) ?> and check for available properties